# How to read random line from remote txt file?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I can not understand how to make a random `string` was taken from a remote file
Now i have this construct. It show me with Toast first line of file.
How can i read a random line?

```
public void bClick(View view) throws IOException {
   String test = new Scanner(new URL("http://www.somesite.us/1.txt").openStream()).
        nextLine();
   Toast.makeText(this, test, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: 1) add all lines to arraylist, 2) get random number from 0 to arraylist size, 3) get elemen t of array list at position from 2)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call nextLine() until you reach the line that you want

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new URL("http://www.somesite.us/1.txt").openStream())
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String test = scanner.nextLine();
             Toast.makeText(this, test, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```